# How to allow access to firewall settings (domain/windows 7)

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, firewall, group-policy, windows-firewall

I'm running a Windows 7 Workstation in a domain setting.

I'd like to disable the local firewall (temporarily), but I am not allowed to do this because of restrictions in the domain.

"For your security, some settings are controlled by group policy"

I'd like to set up a GPO for this particular machine in AD to allow these changes.

(note: I *don't* want to disable the firewall in the GPO/AD, simply remove the restrictions so that it can be done locally)

Comment: I'm confused whether you are a domain admin or not? You talk about admin things, but these are things *any* admin should know. If you're not, ask IT and go through the proper channels.

Comment: @grojo Pls advise how to allow domain users to manage firewall for their systems using domain group policy?

Answer (score 2):

Two questions here: how can one GPO override another, and where are the Win7 firewall settings in Group Policy:

1. Windows Firewall is a computer setting, so  you need to create a new GPO in an OU "closer" to your computer object, or if you create a GPO in the same OU as the existing firewall GPO settings, just ensure it's a higher number in the Link Order for that OU.  Then the original firewall GPO will apply, then your, which will overwrite.
2. Windows Firewall settings are under Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Windows Firewall with Advanced Security

You also don't have to totally disable the firewall to get what you want.  You can change the local fw policy (if allowed) to stay enabled but allow all incoming.  Or add FW rules locally for the ports you want open.

Comment: Hi, note I don't want to disable/enable the FW in the GPO, just make it optional for the local admin. However you're probably right that allowing all incoming is a better solution to temporarily suspend the FW.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the user from that policy, is the easiest and quickest way, instead of amending the policy for everyone.

Or remove the computer account from the container, or OU where the GPO resides.